# What is the difference between copyItemAtPath:toPath:error and copyItemAtURL:toURL:error: of NSFileManager?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsfilemanager

I want to copy a file at path A to path B, in case it exists at B I want it to be overwritten and I want to use one of the mentioned methods but which one is the one I should use?
I saw their [documentation](http://file:///Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index.html#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and they say pretty much the same.

I can make NSURL objects from strings so both do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa is attempting to standardize on URLs.  Consistent use of URLs can in some cases improve performance, because an NSURL object can cache some information from the filesystem and avoid redundant IO in the case that the information is requested again.

However, in the context of just this one method by itself, it doesn't really make any difference.

Comment: Can you point out anywhere in the docs that document 1) Use of URLs can improve performance 2) Some NSURL information is cached 3) Use of URLs avoids redundant IO?